# Doctrine prevent combinations of self referencing in join table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I want to create entity Room, which contains conversations between two users, and extra unique field for this. I implemented it in this way:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="chat_rooms")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cunningsoft\ChatBundle\Repository\RoomRepository")
 */
class Room
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="startedChatting")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="first_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $firstUser;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="joinedChatting")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="second_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $secondUser;
```

User.orm.xml:

```
<one-to-many target-entity="Cunningsoft\ChatBundle\Entity\Room" mapped-by="firstUser" field="startedChatting">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-persist/>
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
        <one-to-many target-entity="Cunningsoft\ChatBundle\Entity\Room" mapped-by="secondUser" field="joinedChatting">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-persist/>
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
```

It works fine, but at the creating instances on the Room side, I can create this records:

```
+------------+-------------+
| first_user | second_user |
+------------+-------------+
|          3 |           4 |
|          4 |           3 |
+------------+-------------+
```

Question is how to prevent duplicates of semantically same data, and which is correct way, do this on the database or on PHP side?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Which it looks like you've already done by adding the @Id to both properties. This would create a composite Primary Key in the database. This would ensure that your table would never have more than a single entry for the same two users for each corresponding field.

This is all predicate on you having foreign keys or, at the least, unique indexes setup on the fields.

You wouldn't want to try and handle this with PHP as you would have to iterate through every single value in your table each time you needed to create a new value, which whichever SQL database provider you are using should be able to handle a lot easier.